# Regex PHP - Starts with and ends with

Tags: php, regex

I've following problem: I'm trying to replace every occurrence of a string that starts with % and also ends % with, in the middle of the precentage symbols there should be alphanumerical chars. and brackets () allowed.
This is what I currently have:

```
/^%[a-zA-Z0-9()]+%$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^%[a-zA-Z0-9()]+%$` would work fine if your percent signs start and end the **line**.  However, I assume this is not the case.

`^` means the beginning of a line, `$` means the end of a line.  I assume you would want just: `%[a-zA-Z0-9()]+%`

Comment: Yes, the end and start line was seemingly my error! Thank you